# Why can't I open my Nikon D3400 raw files in Photoshop CS5.1?

Tags: adobe-camera-raw

I have images taken in RAW on my Nikon D3400 and Photoshop CS 5.1 won't read them. I downloaded both the version of Adobe Camera RAW for Photoshop CS5 and the new updated version and also the DNG converter. It still won't open. When opening in Photoshop, it says the file is from a  camera model not supported by Camera RAW.

Answer (score 2):

From [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/fr/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html), the Nikon D3400 needs ACR (Adobe Camera RAW) **v9.7** (or Lightroom CC / 6.7).

The last version of Camera Raw supported by CS5 is **v6.7** (*Camera Raw 6.7 Update* is the last update of CS5 as you can see on [the official Adobe Photoshop update page](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=39&platform=Windows). It seems that some people copied with success files from ACR v7 (in Lightroom) into the CS5 installation ([link](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3190864#forum-post-41331795)) but I doubt you can do it with the v9.7.

In this new year 2017, some hope remains: **What you can do is download a standalone version of ACR and convert your file into DNG format before opening them with Photoshop CS5**. See [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=106&platform=Windows) to get the converter.

If you want to keep the same workflow and directly work on your RAW, you need to buy the last version of Photoshop...

Comment: Will raw files from newer cameras converted to .dng with the latest version of the DNG convertor not work with older versions of Adobe products?

Comment: Not sure it answers your question, but from Adobe (https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/why-is-my-camera-not-supported.html), using the DNG converter is the easiest way to assure backward compatibility.

Comment: So why not just use the current version of the DNG converter to convert the raw files? Why go through a standalone version of ACR to convert the files?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting. I'm calling it a "standalone" version because the guys from Adobe are calling ACR a plugin when used in Lightroom and Photoshop. The link I provided allows you to download what Adobe call "Adobe Camera Raw and DNG Converter for Windows" and the file that you can download is called "DNGConverter_9_8.exe".

Comment: I think the *title of that page* is named that because there are downloads of both the DNG Converter and downloads of older versions of the Adobe Camera Raw plugin listed on the page. (Hint: scroll down a little)

Comment: thank you, I tried to get support from adobe but they don't help when its about old versions of photoshop. I will have a look at this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it works if you install the latest version of adobe dng converter.

I've asked a friend with cs5 to open a dng file taken with your same camera as yours, D3400. Here is the print screen. You can see the acr version and camera model.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do5bh.jpg

The sample raw file was downloaded from
http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/nikon_d3400_review/sample_images/

Comment: Nope, it's wrong as CS5 doesn't support all camera.

Comment: cs5 does not support all cameras. I said any version of cs can open dng format. I will add a new answer soon.